# Hide server info (kong version) using kong gui plugin response-transformer but didn't work?

Tags: kong, kong-plugin, konga

Hi can anyone help me using kong plugin response-transformer? so basically i just want to hide server info (kong version) on my website using my Kong GUI Dashboard response-transformer plugin but somehow  didn't work? here is my setting for evidence

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohHtV.png)

I try add the kong konfig on my response-transformer plugin like above but it didn't work, it still show my kong version info on my website
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcKpZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Normally Kong will return server headers based on what the [headers](https://docs.konghq.com/gateway/2.7.x/reference/configuration/#headers) configuration is, the default value of this configuration is `server_tokens, latency_tokens`, hence returning Server, Via, and, latencies.
This value is injected to the response after the response transformer plugin run, So that's why you are not able to hide it with response transformer plugin.

Setting headers to off (e.g. `headers = off` in kong.conf) will prevented Kong to return these values entirely.